# Azure x-ms-routing-name to route to deployment slot

Tags: azure

I cannot get `x-ms-routing-name` to do anything when I explicitly specify it in the URL or in a cookie. I am sure I have had it working in the past.

I have a Web App with the default (production) and a deployment slot called "prerelease", which I want to route some customers to as an early access version.

I have gone into 'Testing in Production' configuration and set the "prerelease" slot to 0%. I've tried it both with and without Traffic Manager, and over both HTTP and HTTPS.

I've been through this post and can't see anything else to help me: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-test-in-production-get-start

Why might this not be working?

Comment: I can't get this to work in IE11 all the other browsers i have tried (FF, Edge & Chrome) have worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that this is an intermittent Microsoft Azure bug. The x-ms-routing-name cookie occasionally stops after you swap slots. We have an active support request open with Microsoft. It seems that they fix the problem, but it re-occurs after some time.

Edit: workaround is to go into the app => Testing in Production, make a change to activate the Save button and click save. This will trigger routing to start working again.

Comment: Did you have a response to this?  I've got a case open with MS Support where TiP is disabled immediately after swapping slots, the site stops respecting x-ms-routing-name or dropping/using the cookie (if still present).
Changing the TiP settings and hitting Save immediately starts it working again (until the next swap).

Comment: Yes, changing TiP settings and hitting save is the workaround supplied by MS support. They have confirmed it's a bug but we haven't got an estimate for when it'll be fixed.

Comment: Any news on this bug? Now that Deployment Slots is out of preview and TiP has been removed there doesn’t seem to be a workaround anymore but I still experience the bug...

Comment: No news, but I actually haven't experienced it recently

Comment: I can't get this header to work either, do you need to enable this feature somewhere?

Comment: @orepor you just have to have multiple deployment slots. It isn't a header though, it's a cookie.

Comment: @johnnycardy I obviously do have multiple deployment slots, and the header is enough. For those of you wondering - you need to enable the slot to 1% for the header to work. You can put it back to 0% after